# Keep a UITableViewCell visible when scrolling? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is it possible to make a single `UITableViewCell` stay visible on screen when scrolling (for example, when you scroll down, the cell should always stay visible at the top of the screen). I'm implicitly asking if I can do this with a cell, so don't bother suggesting I should use a table view header or footer, because I was told on this website it's impossible to animate views inside a footer or header view, I REALLY NEED the ability to animate subviews inside the table view (which apparently can only be done in a cell).

So to rephrase: is it in any way possible to keep a cell inside a table view visible at all time when you scroll up or down? If not, is there a 'trick' to animate views inside a footer or header anyway? because like I said, I was told there's no 'legal' way to do this.

Correct me if this is wrong. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
To correct myself on some comments I made earlier: it seems it IS possible to animate subviews inside a footer view, but it doesn't work the same way you animate a cell inside a table view, so if anyone knows how to commit animations inside a footer view, feel free to drop some suggestions. Calling `reloadData()` method of the table view works on table view cells, but the footer view completely ignores `UIView.animate(withDuration:)` and just instantly displays the layout changes without animating them.

**UPDATE:**

```
if self.didTapOnButton == true {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 225/255, blue: 68/255, alpha: 1)
            containerViewTrailingConstraint.constant = 5
            iconImageViewTrailingConstraint.constant = 5
            bubbleViewEqualWidthConstraint.constant = 0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (done:Bool) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                textView.alpha = 1
                doneButton.alpha = 1
            }, completion: { (done:Bool) in
                textView.becomeFirstResponder()
            })
        })
        self.didTapOnButton = false
    }
```

The code that triggers the animations. `self.didTapOnButton` is set to `true` when the button is tapped and immediately after that the table view gets reloaded so this code gets executed once (notice `self.didTapOnButton` gets re-set to `false` after the animation is done). It seems very unlikely the problem is inside this code, though, since it worked perfectly when the cell was still inside the table view, instead of the table view's footer.

Comment: Did you mean to say "table view _section_ header"? I'm asking because they are the views with the desired sticky functionality built-in (also because I'm pretty sure that it's possible to animate inside table view headers). Do you have a link to where you read that it was impossible?

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean. Can't find the link, it was a long time ago so maybe it got deleted, it was with a different account. To be more specific, I want to animate inside a section FOOTER not the header. Do you know how to do it? Calling `reloadData()` can make cells animate but footers don't. In a footer changes within an animation block just instantly happen without animating.

Comment: I just added a test UIView subclass that contained an animated CALayer and it works perfectly.  What sort of animation are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Paulw11 I have a view constrained to all four edges of the cell's content view (by the way, I'm using a `UITableViewCell` as the footer view since I had already made this cell to be the bottom cell of my table view initially). The constant of the view's leading constraint is set to 250 when the view loads so the view looks like a tiny square on the right of the screen. In the animation block (when button is tapped), the constant is set to 0 so the square is supposed to 'expand' to full width of the screen again (like I had initially set it in the Storyboard). Can you picture what it looks it?

Comment: Yes.  Can you show your animation block?  What triggers the animation (ie where is the button?)

Comment: @Paulw11 So basically, the animation animates my view to become wider. It worked perfectly fine when the cell was the bottom cell in my table view, but after it became the footer view, the animation doesn't work anymore and the width change happens instantly.

Comment: @Paulw11 Hang on, I'll copy the code. And the button is inside the view that's expanding.

Comment: @Paulw11 I added some code, even though I don't think you're going to find any problems in there. Like I said, the animation worked fine inside the table view, so the fact that it doesn't anymore, obviously has something to do with the fact that the cell is now a footer view instead of a regular table view cell.

Comment: Generally the only thing that should be inside the `animations` closure is the `layoutIfNeeded`; the changes to the constraints should be outside.

Comment: @Paulw11 It didn't do anything, still not working. I've always animated my views the way I did in the code above, and never ran into any problems, so it seemed very unlikely that it would solve this issue.

Comment: Where is the animation code?  In `viewForFooterInSection` ?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes. This is the last piece of code before returning the `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to animate the view in `viewForFooterInSection` but the footer view is not yet part of the view hierarchy at that point, the animation doesn't occur.  The footer view gets added after this function returns and you just see the post-animation view.

Normally I don't like these sort of time-based 'hacks', but this will address your issue by performing the animation after the footer view is in place and I can't think of any other way of doing it reliably.

```
if self.didTapOnButton == true {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 225/255, blue: 68/255, alpha: 1)
            containerViewTrailingConstraint.constant = 5
            iconImageViewTrailingConstraint.constant = 5
            bubbleViewEqualWidthConstraint.constant = 0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (done:Bool) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                textView.alpha = 1
                doneButton.alpha = 1
            }, completion: { (done:Bool) in
                textView.becomeFirstResponder()
            })
        })
        self.didTapOnButton = false
    }
}
```

Comment: YES! THAT'S IT! IT WORKED! THANK YOU SO MUCH! The stupid thing is not that long ago, I fixed another issue with a `UIAlertController` immediately disappearing after it was presented in the exact same way, so I'm facepalming right now for not thinking of this before. I guess these time-based hacks are like a plan Z you can go for when nothing else works. Second time this is a lifesaver after scratching my head all day long on a stupid layout issue. Thanks again! And oh by the way, I didn't need the `+ 0.1` seconds from your code, just `.now()` did the trick for me. Saved me tenth of a second :)